# How to sequentially show multiple dialogs in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How can I sequentially show multiple dialogs in jQuery Mobile (jQM)?

Opening two dialogs directly in sequence

```
$.mobile.changePage("#dialog1", "pop");
$.mobile.changePage("#dialog2", "pop");
```

results in a chained redirection to

```
 index&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog
```

isOpen from jquery UI doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tie the change event to the first dialog (so when the user selects something) to maybe kick off the second dialog. Example: (Not working but maybe to get you thinking in the right direction) http://jsfiddle.net/LHG4L/18/

Comment: Did it with opening the second dialog in the pagehide event of the first dialog. `$('.dialog').live('pagehide',function(event, ui)`

Comment: nice, will have to remember that