# How to open a jQuery Mobile Dialog from javascript?

Tags: ajax, post, dialog, popup, jquery-mobile

I have a dialog page and am trying to open it and display results from an AJAX POST.

Here is my jQuery success event:

```
success: function(resp) {                               
  $("#dialog").dialog();
  $("#text").html('SPAM and EGGS!')
}
```

My HTML has two pages, the second being the dialog html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  # content 
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="dialog">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Your Message</h1>
  </div>    
  <div data-role="content" id="text">
  </div>    
</div>
```

My AJAX POST is working and element id="text" is being updated with "SPAM and EGGS!", but the dialog is not popping up.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101370/creating-a-dialog-jquery-mobile and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863926/how-to-sequentially-show-multiple-dialogs-in-jquery-mobile/5870158#5870158

Comment: try it with innerHTML, that might do the trick.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add `<a>` tag anywhere in your page, just put your dialog's id as href as shown below: 
`<a id='lnkDialog' href="#dialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" style='display:none;'></a>`

And replace `$("#dialog").dialog();` inside your success event with 
`$("#lnkDialog").click();`

Comment: Hi CodeF0rmer, would you please tell me where the content is placed then? Is it $("#lnkDialog").html( someContent )? Thanks in advance and happy coding  to you too :)

Comment: No. `#lnkDialog` is just a placeholder to be used to open a dialog. Your content will be in `#dialog` in this case.

Answer (score 68):

I think that this one is much more elegant:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#dialog', 'pop', true, true);
```

you should have in your html `data-role="dialog"` instead of `page`

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">...</div>
```

Comment: definitely a more elegant solution.
just tried it and it works.

Comment: not working for me.  JQM does strange things with pageChange that kill the 'x' functionality.  The accepted solution actually works (just hide the link somewhere)

Comment: Good stuff, thanks.  Also this works as long as your dialog has the correct data role as you suggested.  Nice follow-through.
$.mobile.navigate("#dialog");

Answer (score 49):

This answer also works:

```
    $.mobile.changePage('#myPage', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});
```

Comment: Wow this works! Way better than the above mentioned approaches!

Comment: great, official documentation don't tell about this :S

Answer (score 20):

if it is not important to use "dialog" or "popup", try this:

```
$("#dialog").popup('open');
```

Comment: `$("#dialog").popup();` or `$("#dialog").popup('open');` work for me.

Comment: Awesome that worked for me. Was also trying to do this for an hour!

Comment: This is the true solution based on JQM Docs!

Answer (score 5):

correct way with latest query version

```
$.mobile.changePage("#dialog", { transition: "pop",role: "dialog" })
```

Answer (score 1):

As of JQM 1.4 the `changePage` has been deprecated, and will be removed in 1.5
(http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

They suggest that one should use the `change()` method of `pagecontainer` instead.

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#dialog", { transition: 'pop', role: "dialog" });
```