# Can't get dialog to open in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

When the proper value is selected I want to open the div with id="new_firm" in a modal dialog. I can't get the dialog to open. I know that the script get's executed since the alert pops up. Can anyone please tell me what's wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FileReader Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function openNewFirmDialog() {
            var selected = $("#select_firm option:selected");
            var ddValue = selected.text();
            if(ddValue === "Add a new company") {
                //alert(ddValue);
                $('#new_firm').dialog({modal:true});
            }

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="add_details">

        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Register hours</h2>

            <a href="#new_firm" data-rel="dialog">hei</a>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <select id="select_firm" data-native-menu="false" onchange="openNewFirmDialog()">
                <label for="select_firm"  class="select">Select firm:</label>
                <option data-placeholder="firm">Firm</option>
                <option value="internal">Internal</option>
                    <option value="new_firm_option">Add a new company</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <input type="text" id="descritptionTxt" value="Description"/>
            <div data-role="controllgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <input type="range" id="number_of_hours" min="0" max="24" step="0.25" value="0" />
                <input type="range" id="number_of_minutes" min="0" max="24" step="0.25" value="0" />
            </div>


        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="add.html" data-icon="plus">Add hours</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="new_firm">
        <h2>Add a new firm</h2>
        <textarea id="the_new_firm" value="New firm"/>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: jQM support jQuery 1.6.4

Comment: @bobek whenever I try to interact with the page firefox crashes. "Works" fine in chrome.

Comment: when you are in chrome click F12, change tab to Console and refresh the page. Click on the link to open dialog and tell us what is says.

Comment: It doesn't say anything other than that it failed to load two images. And just a little note, if I click on the link "hei", then the dialog appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add reference to jQuery UI if you want to use dialogs. Available for download here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Ok, now I got some sort of dialog when I downloaded and included jquery ui. But I thought this already was in the jquery mobile script?

Comment: Also in the comment @Phill PAfford jquery mobile should be used with jQuery 1.6.4; you use 1.7.1

Comment: Have done that. No change. I can't understand why it works fine with  <a href="#new_firm" data-rel="dialog">hei</a> with the scripts above, and not with the function openNewFirmDialog()

Comment: put your div in new file and link to that page;

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. For now i'm using this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230460/how-to-open-a-jquery-mobile-dialog-from-javascript