# jquery mobile open dialog on click of a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a question about dialog here is the code:

```
<a href="#lol" data-rel="dialog">Filter</a>

<div data-role="dialog" id="lol">
<p><input type="button" value="lolz"/></p>
</div>
```

So I guess on click of "Filter", I should get a dialog with the button, correct? I've read some posts and forums and they all say to do it this way, but for me it doesn't work. No errors in firebug, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230460/how-to-open-a-jquery-mobile-dialog-from-javascript

Comment: Ideas for what? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't post what exactly your issue is, but here are some general guidelines.

You need to make sure your code is properly structured. That the `<a data-rel="dialog">` tag is nested within a `data-role="content"` which is nested within a `data-role="page"` element, and that the `data-role="dialog"` element is a sibling of the `data-role="page"` elements:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#lol" data-rel="dialog">Filter</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="dialog" id="lol">
    <div data-role="content">
        <p><input type="button" value="lolz"/></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kz5QA/

Comment: Can't do that. It sits under one partial in MVC3, and the dialog should display another partial. It's all wrapped in one `data-role="page"`.

Comment: My understanding (and I have used jQuery Mobile a lot) is that you can't do that. `page` or `dialog` elements need to be direct children of the `<body>` tag. Here is a demo of your structure: http://jsfiddle.net/kz5QA/1/ (which won't open the dialog), and here is a demo of my suggested structure: http://jsfiddle.net/kz5QA/ (which works as expected)

Comment: Can't you put your partial together like this? `<div data-role="page>...</div><div data-role="dialog">...</div>`

Comment: It'll still be wrapped in another "page", so it won't work. So, I'll have to get new view, that will be outside of my _Layout and pass it the model from this partial. Thanks for your help, at least now I know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to open dialog from html code  then you have to use in DIV, which you want to from button click - data-role="page" NOT data-role="dialog" which you did there.

And to open dialog from javascript from any event I would suggest code like :

$.mobile.changePage('#divSelectorId', {
                    transition: 'pop',
                    changeHash: true,
                    role: 'dialog' //important to give.
                });